# Verify two instances of same POJO, if one instance produced by mapping of a JSON response. An additional POJO is generated via manual db mapping

Tags: java, automation, rest-assured

I have to validate two POJOs instance of the same POJO
Where one POJO instance is created via Mapping of JSON response
Another POJO instance is created by manually mapping with DB

Now few variables are not required to set via DB in one test case but in another test case it is required.
Currently those variables are Exclude via Lambok but it will not work for multiple test cases

POJO `

```
package com.spotify.oauth2.pojo.LeadResponse;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
//@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"hasSubscriptions","planId","planName","items","inPersonRate","shippingAddress","keyedInRate"})
public class Order {

    @JsonProperty("uuid")
    private String uuid;

    @JsonProperty("hasSubscriptions")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Boolean hasSubscriptions;

    @JsonProperty("planId")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private String planId;

    @JsonProperty("planName")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private String planName;

    @JsonProperty("keyedInRate")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private KeyedInRate keyedInRate;

    @JsonProperty("inPersonRate")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private InPersonRate inPersonRate;

    @JsonProperty("shippingAddress")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private ShippingAddress shippingAddress;

    @JsonProperty("items")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private List<Item> items;

}
```

`
test class

```
 @Test
public void shouldBeAbleToCreateLead() throws Exception {
    String query = "Select * from growth.merchant_lead where email = 'pulkit.agrawal+testingtoday@clover.com' order by created_time desc";
    Lead requestCreateLead = leadBuilder();
    Response response = LeadAPI.put(requestCreateLead);
    assertThat(response.statusCode(), equalTo(StatusCode.CODE_200.getCode()));
    LeadResponse actualResponseLead = response.as(LeadResponse.class);
    JSONArray jsonArray = getDataRows(query);
    LeadResponse expectedResponse = getExpectedResponse(jsonArray);
    boolean result = comparePOJO(actualResponseLead,expectedResponse);
}

@Step
public Lead leadBuilder() {
    Lead lead = new Lead();
    return lead;
}


public static boolean comparePOJO(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
    return obj1.equals(obj2);
}
```

Can a function is created that will ignore default and null values while validating the objects? Also, in case validation failed, should be able to print the difference.

Comment: @EqualsAndHashCode belongs to lombok and it's applied to the POJO itself. In your comparePOJO function, you are converting your POJOs to JSON, then comparing the resulting strings. Why don't you explicitly compare their uuid? Othewise, if I'm understanding what you desire, probably you should to something like `return obj1.equals(obj2)`

Comment: Thanks, I updated the comparePOJO function but still that will not ignore default and null values while validating the objects? Also, in case validation failed, it will not be able to print the difference.

Comment: I think you should annotate your pojo class with `@EqualsAndHashCode`. this will tell lombok to generate the equals and hashCode methods. then you can apply exclusions with `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` on the desired fields. Since you are excluding quite everything, consider using the opposite approach (you can find info here https://www.baeldung.com/java-lombok-equalsandhashcode ). Anyway to ensure that your equals method is acting as expected, try to debug it to analyze what's comparing

Comment: I personally wouldn't recommend coding the object based on how you're going to test it. Code the object for production use and add methods in your test harness for doing the comparisons you feel are appropriate.

Comment: Why would you not override the equals and hashcode methods in the way you need?